# How to add strings of one columns of the dataframe and form another column that will have the incremental value of the original column

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a DataFrame whose data I am pasting below:

```
+---------------+--------------+----------+------------+----------+
|name           |      DateTime|       Seq|sessionCount|row_number|
+---------------+--------------+----------+------------+----------+
|            abc| 1521572913344|        17|           5|         1|
|            xyz| 1521572916109|        17|           5|         2|
|           rafa| 1521572916118|        17|           5|         3|
|             {}| 1521572916129|        17|           5|         4|
|     experience| 1521572917816|        17|           5|         5|
+---------------+--------------+----------+------------+----------+
```

The column `'name'` is of type string. I want a new column `"effective_name"` which will contain the incremental values of `"name"` like shown below:

```
+---------------+--------------+----------+------------+----------+-------------------------+
|name          | DateTime |sessionSeq|sessionCount|row_number |effective_name|
+---------------+--------------+----------+------------+----------+-------------------------+
|abc            |1521572913344 |17        |5           |1         |abc                      |
|xyz            |1521572916109 |17        |5           |2         |abcxyz                   |
|rafa           |1521572916118 |17        |5           |3         |abcxyzrafa               |
|{}             |1521572916129 |17        |5           |4         |abcxyzrafa{}             |
|experience     |1521572917816 |17        |5           |5         |abcxyzrafa{}experience   |
+---------------+--------------+----------+------------+----------+-------------------------+
```

The new column contains the incremental concatenation of its previous values of the `name` column.

Comment: Are you ordering by `clientDateTime` or `row_number`? Any `groupBy()`s?

Comment: @Chaitanya I rolled back your edit. Don't post [pictures of code or data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: @pault- the data is dummy

Comment: @AshishAcharya I am trying to concatenate using lag function

Comment: @pault i am ordering by clientDateTime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a [`pyspark.sql.Window`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window), which orders by the `clientDateTime`, [`pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws), and [`pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list):

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.orderBy("DateTime")  # define Window for ordering

df.drop("Seq", "sessionCount", "row_number").select(
    "*",
    f.concat_ws(
        "",
        f.collect_list(f.col("name")).over(w)
    ).alias("effective_name")
).show(truncate=False)
#+---------------+--------------+-------------------------+
#|name           |      DateTime|effective_name           |
#+---------------+--------------+-------------------------+
#|abc            |1521572913344 |abc                      |
#|xyz            |1521572916109 |abcxyz                   |
#|rafa           |1521572916118 |abcxyzrafa               |
#|{}             |1521572916129 |abcxyzrafa{}             |
#|experience     |1521572917816 |abcxyzrafa{}experience   |
#+---------------+--------------+-------------------------+
```

I dropped `"Seq"`, `"sessionCount"`, `"row_number"` to make the output display friendlier.

If you needed to do this per group, you can add a `partitionBy` to the `Window`. Say in this case you want to group by `sessionSeq`, you can do the following:

```python
w = Window.partitionBy("Seq").orderBy("DateTime")

df.drop("sessionCount", "row_number").select(
    "*",
    f.concat_ws(
        "",
        f.collect_list(f.col("name")).over(w)
    ).alias("effective_name")
).show(truncate=False)
#+---------------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+
#|name           |      DateTime|sessionSeq|effective_name           |
#+---------------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+
#|abc            |1521572913344 |17        |abc                      |
#|xyz            |1521572916109 |17        |abcxyz                   |
#|rafa           |1521572916118 |17        |abcxyzrafa               |
#|{}             |1521572916129 |17        |abcxyzrafa{}             |
#|experience     |1521572917816 |17        |abcxyzrafa{}experience   |
#+---------------+--------------+----------+-------------------------+
```

If you prefer to use `withColumn`, the above is equivalent to:

```python
df.drop("sessionCount", "row_number").withColumn(
    "effective_name",
    f.concat_ws(
        "",
        f.collect_list(f.col("name")).over(w)
    )
).show(truncate=False)
```

---

**Explanation**

You want to apply a function over multiple rows, which is called an aggregation. With any aggregation, you need to define which rows to aggregate over and the order. We do this using a `Window`. In this case, `w = Window.partitionBy("Seq").orderBy("DateTime")` will partition the data by the `Seq` and sort by the `DateTime`.

We first apply the aggregate function `collect_list("name")` over the window. This gathers all of the values from the `name` column and puts them in a list. The order of insertion is defined by the Window's order.

For example, the intermediate output of this step would be:

```python
df.select(
    f.collect_list("name").over(w).alias("collected")
).show()
#+--------------------------------+
#|collected                       |
#+--------------------------------+
#|[abc]                           |
#|[abc, xyz]                      |
#|[abc, xyz, rafa]                |
#|[abc, xyz, rafa, {}]            |
#|[abc, xyz, rafa, {}, experience]|
#+--------------------------------+
```

Now that the appropriate values are in the list, we can concatenate them together with an empty string as the separator.

```python
df.select(
    f.concat_ws(
        "",
        f.collect_list("name").over(w)
    ).alias("concatenated")
).show()
#+-----------------------+
#|concatenated           |
#+-----------------------+
#|abc                    |
#|abcxyz                 |
#|abcxyzrafa             |
#|abcxyzrafa{}           |
#|abcxyzrafa{}experience |
#+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Pault ...sessionSeq is required in the final dataframe which I will write. I will drop other two columns.. Can i use PartitionBy("sessionSeq") in window option as i need this for only particular sessionSeq

Comment: @ChaitanyaKirty yes you can do that. I edited the answer to show an example.

Comment: also. i need the new column ''effective_feature_toggles" in dataframe..shouldn't i use df.withColumn() option?

Comment: You can do either- `df = df.select("*", ...)` or `df = df.withColumn(...)`. I will add an example of how to use `withColumn`. In both cases, make sure you don't have `.show()` at the end- that is just for display and it returns `None`.

Comment: Underrated answer of the year

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

import pyspark.sql.functions as f

w = Window.partitionBy("Seq").orderBy("DateTime")

df.select(
    "*",
    f.concat_ws(
        "",
        f.collect_set(f.col("name")).over(w)
    ).alias("cummuliative_name")
).show()

**Explanation**

collect_set() - This function returns value like [["abc","xyz","rafa",{},"experience"]] .

concat_ws() - This function takes the output of collect_set() as input and converts it into abc, xyz, rafa, {}, experience

**Note:**
Use *collect_set()* if you don't have duplicates or else use *collect_list()*