# groupby and convert multiple columns into a list using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pyspark. So I have a spark dataframe that looks like:

```
a | b | c
5 | 2 | 1
5 | 4 | 3
2 | 4 | 2
2 | 3 | 7
```

Need Output:

```
a | b_list
5 | 2,1,4,3
2 | 4,2,3,7
```

It's important to keep the sequence as given in output.

Comment: On what is the data frame currently ordered?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele Didn't understand your question, but I want to groupby on column a, and get b,c into a list as given in the output. In pandas, it's a one line answer, I can't figure out in pyspark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following results in the last 2 columns aggregated into an array column:

```
df1 = df.withColumn('lst', f.concat(df['b'], f.lit(','), df['c']).alias('lst'))\
  .groupBy('a')\
  .agg( f.collect_list('lst').alias('b_list'))
```

Now join array elements:

```
#Simplistic udf to joing array:
def join_array(col):
    return ','.join(col)

join = f.udf(join_array)

df1.select('a', join(df1['b_list']).alias('b_list'))\
  .show()
```

Printing:

```
+---+-------+
|  a| b_list|
+---+-------+
|  5|2,1,4,3|
|  2|4,2,3,7|
+---+-------+
```

Comment: You could use [`pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws) to do the join which will be faster than using a udf.

Comment: @pault thanks. Not sure I misread, but when I first looked at it, it seemed to want string columns as input, but I had arrays to pass in. Will take another look when I get some time...

Comment: You can pass an array (like the output of `collect_list`) to `concat_ws` - for example, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50047877/5858851).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of udf, for joining the list, we can also use [`concat_ws`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws) function as suggested in comments above, like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = (df
      .withColumn('lst', F.concat(df['b'], F.lit(','), df['c']).alias('lst'))
      .groupBy('a')
      .agg( F.concat_ws(',', F.collect_list('lst').alias('b_list')).alias('lst')))

df.show()

+---+-------+
|  a|    lst|
+---+-------+
|  5|2,1,4,3|
|  2|4,2,3,7|
+---+-------+
```