# PySpark dataframe: Creating sequence variables for all categorical columns for each id sorted by date

Tags: loops, dataframe, pyspark, window, sequence

Using PySpark dataframe I am trying to develop sequence for categorical variables.
So for each ID, I need to sort by date and combine the column values of each categorical column as depicted in the output below. For a specific ID, the categorical sequence value should be from start of datetime to current datetime of the record being affected and the values should be space seperated for each record.
Note that there  should be no loss of records here.

**INPUT:**

### transaction_table

```
+----+------------------------------+------+-------+------+
| id |             date             | cat1 | cat2  | cat3 |
+----+------------------------------+------+-------+------+
|  1 |         2018-01-25 00:00:... | C    | Text1 | val1 |
|  1 |         2018-01-25 00:00:... | A    | Text1 | val3 |
|  1 |         2018-01-25 00:00:... | B    | Text5 | val5 |
|  2 |         2018-01-26 00:00:... | A    | Text2 | val1 |
|  2 |         2018-01-26 00:00:... | A    | Text1 | val2 |
|  3 |         2018-01-27 00:00:... | C    | Text6 | val1 |
|  3 |         2018-01-29 00:00:... | A    | Text2 | val9 |
|  3 |         2018-01-29 00:00:... | C    | Text6 | val5 |
|  3 |         2018-02-05 00:00:... | A    | Text1 | val3 |
+----+------------------------------+------+-------+------+
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
+----+------------------------------+----------+-------------------------+---------------------+
| id |             date             | cat1_seq |        cat2_seq         |      cat3_seq       |
+----+------------------------------+----------+-------------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |         2018-01-25 00:00:... | C        | Text1                   | val1                |
|  1 |         2018-01-25 00:00:... | C A      | Text1 Text1             | val1 val3           |
|  1 |         2018-01-25 00:00:... | C A B    | Text1 Text1 Text5       | val1 val3 val5      |
|  2 |         2018-01-26 00:00:... | A        | Text2                   | val1                |
|  2 |         2018-01-26 00:00:... | A A      | Text2 Text1             | val1 val2           |
|  3 |         2018-01-27 00:00:... | C        | Text6                   | val1                |
|  3 |         2018-01-29 00:00:... | C A      | Text6 Text2             | val1 val9           |
|  3 |         2018-01-29 00:00:... | C A C    | Text6 Text2 Text6       | val1 val9 val5      |
|  3 |         2018-02-05 00:00:... | C A C A  | Text6 Text2 Text6 Text1 | val1 val9 val5 val3 |
+----+------------------------------+----------+-------------------------+---------------------+
```

Solved:
I have used the following code as suggested by @Pault to get it done--

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window
df1 = df.select("*", *[f.concat_ws(" ",f.collect_list(c).over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date"))).alias(c + "_seq") for c in df.columns])
```

Comment: There's no question here...are you looking for something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50047493/how-to-add-strings-of-one-columns-of-the-dataframe-and-form-another-column-that/50047877#50047877)?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `from pyspark.sql import Window; df.select("*", *[f.collect_list(c).over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date")).alias(c + "_seq") for c in df.columns])`

Comment: @pault, apologies, I was editing the question. Can you have a look at it now.

Comment: Thanks @pault for your valuable input. The output of this is an array and hence appears as [C,A,B] . Will need to make it appear as string C A B

Comment: The answer [linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50047877/5858851) shows you how to do this. If it's not working, please [edit] your question to show what you've tried and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add strings of one columns of the dataframe and form another column that will have the incremental value of the original column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50047493/how-to-add-strings-of-one-columns-of-the-dataframe-and-form-another-column-that)